# Commiting to BitBucket with a GUI based tool

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I am following the steps listed here:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+Git+and+Mercurial?utm_source=internal&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=blank_repo

and created a Mercurial repo and have also installed TurtoiseHG ...but still when the tutorial goes to the section on how to add code to this repo from our local machine, it is sill doing it via command line and those unix like commands that always freak me out :) So there isn't a GUI tool like the one we have for TurtoiseSVN to just right click on a working copy and boom! commit.

Comment: Yes. Don't you see "hg commit" when you right click with TortoiseHg installed? (Keep in mind that "commit" might not mean what you think it means if you're used to svn; you also need to `hg push`, which  TortoiseHg calls "synchronize" to get it to bitbucket.)

Comment: You can add code to the repo using the TortoiseHG GUI. I do it all the time. That said the Tortoise HG UI is a UX nightmare, so sometimes it is hard to find the option in the UI. The best tip I can offer is that some of those buttons on the toolbar are actually TABS even though they don't look like it.

Comment: Thanks. Ok so I have a URL to an empty repo I created on BitBucket, and I have a File on my desktop. Let's say I want to push this file to that URL Repo.  What should I set in GUI tool to do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are even instructions for TortoiseHG in the official Bitbucket wiki, three pages after the link you posted.

Check this out:
[Fork a Repo, Compare Code, and Create a Pull Request](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Fork+a+Repo,+Compare+Code,+and+Create+a+Pull+Request)

Yes, the page is about forking a repository in the first place using the Bitbucket web GUI.
But once you have forked a repository, the steps to get it on your machine, change it and push back to the server are exactly the same.

These two steps in the link above describe the exact workflow, including TortoiseHG screenshots:

- Step 2. Clone your fork
- Step 3. Make a change to the repository source

---

You can also read [A Quick Start Guide to TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.4/quick.html) in the official TortoiseHG documentation.
([Step 4.8 "Fetching from the group repository"](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.4/quick.html#fetching-from-the-group-repository) describes cloning.)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest checking out the [TortoiseHG documentation](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.4/commit.html). You can definitely do this from the GUI.

[image: TortoiseHG Commit Screen]

If you are moving from a non DVCS like SVN, keep in mind that you have a two step commit process with these tools (COMMIT/PUSH) before the code is posted into BitBucket. The first step (COMMIT) just pushes it to a local copy of the repository.

If you aren't comfortable using a command line syntax, the [TortoiseHG Workbench](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.4/workbench.html?highlight=workbench) is going to be your best friend.